# How do I include a variable in a ksh command subtitution?

Tags: shell, ksh, command-substitution

I'm trying to find a number of lines that match a regex pattern in grep received as a variable. When I do the grep with the pattern directly in the command substitution, it works. When I use a variable for the pattern, it doesn't.

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern="'^\\\".*\\\"$'"
echo "pattern : $(echo $pattern)"
NB=$(grep -c -E -v -e ${pattern} abc.txt)
NB2=$(grep -v -c -E -e '^\".*\"$' abc.txt)
echo " -> $NB , $NB2"
```

Besides what's in the code, I've tried:

```
NB=$(grep -c -E -v -e $(echo $pattern) abc.txt)
```

No success.

```
cmd="grep -c -E -v -e ${pattern} abc.txt"
NB="$($cmd)"
```

No success.

In the example, `abc.txt` file contains 3 lines:

```
"abc"
"abc
abc"
```

The pattern in the variable seems ok:

```
pattern : '^\".*\"$'
```

I'm expecting that the 2 numbers in NB and NB2 are the same. If you look in the code, the actual result is:

```
pattern : '^\".*\"$'
 -> 3 , 2
```

I expect:

```
pattern : '^\".*\"$'
 -> 2 , 2
```

Comment: Is it ksh or bash? Your writeup says ksh, your shebang line says `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NB2=$(grep -v -c -E -e '^\".*\"$' abc.txt)
```

If that works, then assign that exact regex to `$pattern`. Don't add more backslashes and quotes.

```
pattern='^\".*\"$'
```

It's always a good idea to quote variable expansions to prevent unwanted wildcard expansion and word splitting.

```
NB=$(grep -c -E -v -e "${pattern}" abc.txt)
#                     ^          ^
```